# how to integrate send grid smtp details on ossec.conf file

Tags: sendgrid

I have a send grid account for smtp so that I can get alerts from ossec server 
in ossec.conf file I need to put the smtp server address, user name and password
I am not sure about the syntax of it and unable to get proper syntax in google too, please help me.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic as it has nothing to do with programming and fits better in ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Anxton, I found the answer as there is no direct way to integrate smtp with authentication in ossec we need to bring up smtpd and configure the credentials in smtpd so that ossec can send it to smtpd.